# What's the technology behind Skype's anit-shake video recording?

Tags: iphone, ios, algorithm, video-processing, core-motion

Skype added [an anti-shake feature](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/09/27/skype-for-iphone-ipad-gets-anti-shake-bluetooth-support/) in it's video conference app on iPhone. How can that be done?

Comment: Image processing algorithms? Seriously, this is a much bigger question than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a complicated thing to pull off, but it's probably a combination of some powerful blur detection/removal algorithms, and the gyroscope. I would start by looking into [how to detect motion](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html) with the iPhone, and see what kind of results you can get with that. If it's not enough, start looking into [shift/blur direction detection algorithms](http://www.guthspot.se/video/deshaker.htm). This is not a trivial problem, but is something that you could probably accomplish given enough time. Hope that Helps!

Comment: I am also thinking along the motion detection line ... As video conference does not need 30 fps, it's possible to keep _good_ frames (little motion detected) and throw away bad frames (lots of motion detected). Too bad the discussed has to be _CLOSED_.